# How to get the max value of a variable? Xquery

Tags: xml, max, xquery

I know there's a function called max() but it won't work obviously as $puntuacion hasn't got a collection, but single values displayed dinamically. So, how can I get the biggest match score?

```css
/* this is xquery */
for $match in //summary
let $puntuacion := sum($match/team/@score)
return max($puntuacion)
```

```html
<!-- this is key part of xml -->
<match>  
    <summary>
        <team name="Wales" score="19">
        </team>
        <team name="England" score="26">
        </team>
    </summary>
    <summary>
        <team name="Italy" score="11">
        </team>
        <team name="Ireland" score="13">
        </team>
    </summary>
</match>
<match>  
    <summary>
        <team name="Spain" score="20">
        </team>
        <team name="Croatia" score="15">
        </team>
    </summary>
    <summary>
        <team name="Germany" score="40">
        </team>
        <team name="France" score="36">
        </team>
    </summary>
</match>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's deconstruct your query: it says take the sequence of summary elements, and for each of them, compute the sum of the scores within that summary (i.e. add up the score from each team), and then take the max of that single value.

If you want to get the maximum of those values, you need the max call to be wrapped around the FLWOR expression: `max(for $match in //summary return sum($match/team/@score))`

Comment: OMG! So simple and beautifull hahaah… Cant believe I've been an hour with this... big thanks!